# How to check the invertibity of the following map

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following question and I need help:

> Let $f \colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be defined by $\,f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2+x_3,x_3+x_1,x_1+x_2)$ . Then the first derivative of $f$ is :
>
> 1. not invertible anywhere
> 2. invertible only at the origin
> 3. invertible anywhere except at the origin
> 4. invertible everywhere

*My Attempt*: We see that the derivative is a linear transformation $f':\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that its matrix is

$$[f']=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}
\end{array} \right)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &1 \\ 
 1&0  &1 \\ 
 1&1  &0 
\end{bmatrix} $$ and the matrix representation of $f'$ is invertible.So,option 1 can not be right. But I am confused about how to check the invertibility at the origin. I can not decide which of 2,3,4 will be the  correct choice. Can someone help?

Comment: Notice that the derivatives are constants: don’t involve the variables at all. So?

Comment: @Lubin I still could not get it. Would you explain a bit more?

Comment: It might help if you looked at a more complicated example, like what you get when you take your original formulas, and square all the appearances of variables there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: as Lubin says in his comment, all of the partial derivatives involve only constant terms.  Keep in mind, that, when you're computing f'(x), you're computing it at a point x=a (i.e. computing all of the partial derivatives at this point).

Now, given arbitrary a, what is f'(a) here?

Comment: So,if I get the hint right,then option 4 is the right choice.Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, because the derivative is constant and thus doesn't depend on the point at which you take it.  You yourself showed it is invertible, and there you have your answer.